# snaphu export error using SNAP

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I used SNAP Sentinel 1 to calculate subsidence. After snaphu export I open `snaphu.conf` and copy command as below then run it in Terminal. I got the following error in picture:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your windows command prompt does not recognize the `snaphu` command and does not know what to do when you enter `snaphu`. This can have two reasons:

1. snaphu is not an official part of SNAP, you have to download it separately: https://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/snaphu/ (at the bottom of the page, "Manual snaphu installation")
2. You have to add the directory where snaphu.exe was downloaded to your system's `path` variable. An explanation is given [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). 
   Restart your command prompt and type `snaphu` again to check if it works. It should now show something like this: 
   [image]
   If this is the case, you can run the snaphu command as created in the config file.

Comment: Thank you so much for help> I installed the snaphu in SNAP as plugin , but I did not find snaphu.exe in my PC

Comment: Downloading the plugin for SNAP is not enough, (this only creates an entry in the menu). You also have to install the bundles as described in this tutorial: 
http://step.esa.int/docs/tutorials/S1TBX%20TOPSAR%20Interferometry%20with%20Sentinel-1%20Tutorial_v2.pdf
You will be asked for download directory during this process.
I still recommend to use snaphu from the command line.

Comment: Thank you so much